# CSS full-width centered navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I would like to get this in CCS3 / HTLM5

```
             | Header ....                  |
=====Blue bar| Navbar. Menu1. Menu2 ...     |Blue bar========
             | Website leftSide and content |
             | Footer                       |
```

The menu is centered, as well as the content. The problems are the 2 "blue bars" to the right and to the left of the menu. I don't know how to draw them in CSS. They should be the same height as the navbar.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div id="wrapper">

    <header id="header">
        Image + Login
        <br /><br /><br />

        <div id="nav">
            <ul id="nav">
              <li id="nav-accueil"><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
              <li id="nav-coursATelecharger"><a href="#">Cours</a></li>
              <li id="nav-coursPrives"><a href="#">Cours</a></li>
              <li id="nav-coursEnGroupe"><a href="#">Cours</a></li>
              <li id="nav-contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header><!-- #header-->

    <section id="middle">

        <div id="container">
            <div id="content">

            </div><!-- #content-->
        </div><!-- #container-->

        <aside id="sideLeft">

        </aside><!-- #sideLeft -->

    </section><!-- #middle-->

    <footer id="footer">
    </footer><!-- #footer -->

</div><!-- #wrapper -->
```

And here is the CSS:

```
header, nav, section, article, aside, footer {
    display: block;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
}


#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Header
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#header {
    height: 100px;
}


/* Middle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#middle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1%;
    position: relative;
}
#middle:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content {
    padding: 0 0 0 200px;
}


/* Sidebar Left
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#sideLeft {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    margin-left: -100%;
    position: relative;
}


/* Footer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#footer {
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 1px dashed #999;
    padding-top: 0.4em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #888;
}
/* End of Layout */


/* Navigation */
#nav ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#ddd;
    width:960px;
    float:left;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#nav a:link,
#nav a:visited {
    color:#333;
    background:#ddd;
    padding: 0.4em 0.6em 0.4em 0.6em;
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#888;
}
#nav li:first-child a {
}
/* End of navigation*/
```

How can I get my website of 960px fully centered and having the 2 "blue bars" beside the menu?

Thank you for reading and happy coding!

Comment: does the nav need to be fixed ? The way you would get around this is by having header outside of wrapper :) I'll write jsfiddle for you in a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is how I'd solve it. You'd need to put the header outside of the wrapper. then set a parent background and ul to different colors.

EXAMPLE

```
nav {
    width:100%;
    background:blue;
}
nav ul {
    width:100%;
    max-width:960px;
    list-style-type:none;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

DEMO
http://jsfiddle.net/6vPKN/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Actually, the whole site is 960px centered except for the menu bar, which has 2 blue bars to each side of the menu (and of the same height of the menu).